# Unpacking image with URL-Loader in Webpack still failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, urlloader

I'm just trying to get url-loader setup so I can display images in my React App, and I keep getting the error: `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�'`

I have this in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192
        }
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Just for good measure, I've also included this in `module.loaders`:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then in my `.jsx` file I import like this:

```
import addrecipe from '../../images/addrecipe.png';
```

And then display like this:

```
<img src={addrecipe} />
```

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Comment: @JoeLissner 1:0

Answer (score 0):

Which version of webpack are you using? I'm currently using the following for images with version `3.2.0` and url-loader of `0.5.9`.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(gif|png|svg|jpe?g)$/i,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 8192
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: looks like webpack `3.1.0` and url-loader `0.6.2`

Comment: What does your entire `module` object look like?

Comment: Try [here](https://github.com/KonstantinSimeonov/cv/blob/master/webpack/webpack.base.js)